# Ignoring self signed certificate on apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https, certificate, self-signed

The main idea is i want to upgrade my real webpage to https, but it's in production and i want to make this upgrade in my local server to be sure it's working properly and after that move all changes to production. So i'm trying to create local https website but my browser Google Chrome give me error. I wrote this commands in my linux terminal for creating self signed certificate

```
    sudo openssl req -new -sha256 -out new.ssl.csr
    sudo openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out new.cert.key
    sudo openssl x509 -in new.ssl.csr -out new.cert.cert -req -signkey new.cert.key -days 256
    sudo cp new.cert.cert /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    sudo cp new.cert.key /etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

And i changed my host configuration file like this

```
    VirtualHost *:80
        ServerName localsite
        DocumentRoot /var/www/localsite

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localsite_access.log combined
    VirtualHost

    VirtualHost *:443
        ServerAdmin asdasdasd@asd.asd
        ServerName localsite.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/localsite

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localsite_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +StrictRequire
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    VirtualHost
```

```
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

And after it i export certificate from my file and import it to Google Chrome and still having `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04) to create a self-signed certificate. It looks like what you did to create one.

I forgot to fill in the `Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)`. You can leave all fields empty, but this one should be answered. In your example, it should be `localsite.local`.

After creating your certificate, upload it to `chrome://settings/certificates` and the padlock will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

If you use self signed certificate, browsers will alert you error like that.

So you should use certificate signed by known authorities.
I have ever used letsencrypt.

For that, you should purchase your own domain name for your site at first.

Comment: There is no need to have an authorized certificate for (local) development.